# how to pass controller data into component and back up in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-components, ember-controllers

I have an ember 2.13 app that has a users route fetching a users model.
So in the users template I am showing all the users fetched.
I also have a users controller that feeds data to an edit form when a user is clicked. I'm using the user controller to do this.

All the code is in a single template but I would like to put the rendering user list and edit user form in two separate components. Let's say I make a render-single-user and edit-user templates. So when a user clicks on a user in rendered using the render-single-user component, data of this user should show up in the dom rendered by edit-user component.

The problem is a component doesn't have access to the route's model or the app's store.

I would be grateful if someone would tell me how to pass the model and store from controller to the components and also between the render-single-user and edit-user components. And when a user clicks update/save the modified data should travel up to the controller and save the record to the store consequently making a post request to the server.

Screenshots attached.

User View

[image]

Clicked User

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer applies to versions 2.x.x and was written as of 2.15.

It sounds like you're just getting started in Ember. Welcome! I highly encourage you to do the [Tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/tutorial/ember-cli/) and read [The Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/). They are an investment - things will go much faster and be much easier for you afterwards. Everything I'm about to tell you is available there. They are not skippable.

In your users route:

```
model() {
   return this.store.findAll('users')
}
```

In your users controller:

```
actions: {
  consoleLogger(thingToLog) {
    console.log(thingToLog)
  }
}
```

Data and actions are passed from controllers and routes down to components. This is done through the handlebars templates.

Generic example of passing actions, model, and variables to a component:

```
{{some-component 
   someControllerVariable=someControllerVariable
   mode=model 
   consoleLogger=(action "consoleLogger")}}
```

Then in your component, you can either use the action like this:

```
<button {{action consoleLogger "string to log"}}>Log it</button>
```

Or use it in your component js like this:

```
this.get('consoleLogger')("string to log");
// this.get retrieves the function and then we call it with an argument, kind of like how you'd do someOtherFunction() in plain js
```

Since you need to show a list of helpers, you will need to use the [each helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) in your route:

```
{{#each users as |user|}}
       {{user-list-item 
       someControllerVariable=someControllerVariable
       user=user 
       consoleLogger=(action "consoleLogger")}}
{{/each}}
```

When the action is used in your component, you can pass records as arguments. They'll go to the controller action and that's where you should do your POST/PATCH/DELETE type operations like save().

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @handlebears for the prompt yet lengthy reply :) I have read the guides and tutorial several times, but I guess i kind of forget which to use for what. Your detailed suggestion helps though. Thanks a bunch again.